# Should we synonymize these tags: scope, off-topic, on-topic-definition?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition

I see that there are 3 tags with similar usage:

| Tag | Description |
| --- | --- |
| [scope](/questions/tagged/scope) | Scope refers to "site scope," the area of topic focus within which users are permitted to ask questions. For example, questions about software design are generally considered within the scope of Software Engineering; questions about legal matters are not. |
| [off-topic](/questions/tagged/off-topic) | No description |
| [on-topic-definition](/questions/tagged/on-topic-definition) | No description |

Should these tags be synonymized?

Comment: it seems that this question is uninterested. Why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is done.

[As suggested by Doc Brown](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9546/4), I merged [scope](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scope) and [off-topic](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/off-topic) into [on-topic-definition](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/on-topic-definition) and set up the appropriate synonyms with [on-topic-definition](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/on-topic-definition) as the master. Everything historically and going forward should have the correct tag.

Answer (score 3):

Good idea, I support this.

I would have preferred to make [scope](/questions/tagged/scope) the master tag of the two others, hence I started with the proposal of making [off-topic](/questions/tagged/off-topic) a synonym for [scope](/questions/tagged/scope).

Then I tried the same with [on-topic-definition](/questions/tagged/on-topic-definition). This lead to an error message saying this wasn't possible,since there are currently more than 1.25 questions tagged with [on-topic-definition](/questions/tagged/on-topic-definition) than with [scope](/questions/tagged/scope).

So my next try was to make [on-topic-definition](/questions/tagged/on-topic-definition) the master tag for [scope](/questions/tagged/scope) as well as for [off-topic](/questions/tagged/off-topic). Unfortunately, both of those attempts failed, because of the pending vote [off-topic](/questions/tagged/off-topic) -> [scope](/questions/tagged/scope).

Maybe I screwed this up, and the system does not offer me any way to retract my first proposal (note this was a [feature request from 2010](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61337/request-to-be-able-to-delete-tag-synonyms), but it seems SE's staff did not implement this in the last 13 years). Maybe we just have to wait now until the voting is over, maybe we need help from a diamond mod or from the SE staff, I don't know. I guess I will recheck the status in a few weeks.

Here is the voting page of [scope](/questions/tagged/scope),

https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/scope/synonyms

**To all of you with voting privileges for tag synonyms: it would be really nice if you could cast a downvote for this accidentally proposed synonym "off-topic".**

Then we can start a new proposal to make [scope](/questions/tagged/scope) and [off-topic](/questions/tagged/off-topic) synonyms for the master [on-topic-definition](/questions/tagged/on-topic-definition).

Comment: Why would the system require that?

Comment: @Ooker: I tried it out and got the message *"Can't create synonym; the 'on-topic-definition' tag appears more than 1.25 times the 'scope' tag"*. If you want to know why this constraint exists, ask on https://meta.stackexchange.com/